# How to port a linux driver , which is compiled in 2.6 kernel ,without compiling in other new version of kernel

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

Thanks to every one,

This is the question asked in one of the interview i faced.

I have a Linux device driver which was compiled in Linux kernel version 2.6.I would like to port the same driver in a Linux PC which has kernel 3.X without compiling in new versions.

Is it possible ? If it is possible please let me know how. If it is not possible please let me know why not ?

Thanks & Regards
Siva

Comment: *porting* your driver will generally involve code-changes. if you change code, but are not allowed to recompile, how will you ever get a kernel-module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot port module which is compiled for one version to other version.

The reason is as follows

`Modules are strongly tied to the data structures and function prototypes defined in a particular kernel version;
the interface seen by a module can change significantly from one kernel version to
the next. This is especially true of development kernels, of course`

`The kernel does not just assume that a given module has been built against the
proper kernel version. One of the steps in the build process is to link your module
against a file (called vermagic.o) from the current kernel tree; this object contains a
fair amount of information about the kernel the module was built for, including the
target kernel version, compiler version, and the settings of a number of important
configuration variables. When an attempt is made to load a module, this information
can be tested for compatibility with the running kernel. If things don’t match,`

the module is not loaded; instead, you see something like:

`# insmod hello.ko`

`Error inserting './hello.ko': -1 Invalid module format`

A look in the system log file (/var/log/messages or whatever your system is configured
to use) will reveal the specific problem that caused the module to fail to load.

Kernel interfaces often change between releases. If you are writing a module that is
intended to work with multiple versions of the kernel (especially if it must work
across major releases), you likely have to make use of macros and #ifdef constructs
to make your code build properly.

Comment: Suppose i am forcing like # insmod -f hello.ko what will happen

Comment: If you try to force you ll see the message like above only.Error inserting './hello.ko': -1 Invalid module format. also if u see `dmesg` you can see "disagree about version of the symbol module_layout

Answer (score 1):

now it's not possible:

- usually, a "driver" is a binary kernel-module
- *porting* will involve code-changes to the kernel module. if you change the code, you need to compile it, in order to get a binary.
- since kernel modules run in kernel space, it is crucial that they are robust. since parts of the kernel-API change every now and then, trying to use a module compiled for kernel-X with another kernel-Y, might either not load because of missing symbols (if you are lucky) or lead to a kernel panic because semantics have changed.
- btw, all this is not really related to `2.6.x` vs `3.y`, but holds true for any kernel version

but then: of course in theory it is possible to "write" a kernel-module as binary code in your favourite hex-editor, without resorting to compilers and such. this would allow you to "port" a driver from one kernel to another without recompilation. i guess this is not for humans though...